# What is the way to count viewer on a post

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a example table to store posts like

```
id|title|content|
```

now i want count `view post` like

[image]

What is the way to do that thanks

Comment: Did you try anything so far ? It's something really easy you could find out within 5 minutes anywhere on the Internet

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL best way to count page views for dynamic pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599335/php-mysql-best-way-to-count-page-views-for-dynamic-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a field in your table to store the views count, so you can update the count of viewers with something similar to:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id`= $post_id
```

You may want to avoid spamming by refreshing the page or make sure its a unique viewer. There are several ways you can do that.

If you want to be serious about it you will have to use a table to store IP addresses and relate them to viewed posts in order to not count again, [like Gautam3164 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18566693/156811).

But creating new records every time a client view a post can be too computationally expensive and, unless its strictily necessary for the case, it should be avoided.

You can instead abuse the `$_SESSION` to store the IDs of the recently viewed posts, in order to not increment the counter if the same client view them again.

For instance:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['recent_posts'][$post_id])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id`= $post_id");
    $_SESSION['recent_posts'][$post_id] = 1;
}
```

It should solve the spam problem in a very simple and cheap way.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to store the `IP`address of the viewer using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` of the page was opened and store it in `DB` with that `page id` and each time you need to check for the maintaining the unique `IP` addresses.

Means you need to enable the increment of the `page view count` for the **single** IP address.

**1)** First Check for the DB that whether the page view with the current `IP` address(`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`).

**2)** If is already exists then do nothing.

**3)** If there is no ,then add a row into DB with the current page id and ip address.

**4)** Then extract/count the number of views as counting the rows from DB with that page id.

Every time you need to repeat these things.You can also use `LOGIN` system for mainting the page count.

Comment: But IP address keeps changing every time. How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to add one column in your table.

For example lets say,

You have column name `Views`

You have to put `update` query on the top of the page like this

```
 UPDATE table SET Views= Views+1 WHERE ID= 'current page id'
```

Comment: then he can keep refreshing the page and update query will update the record and thats not good

Comment: Refreshing is not the part of view page more than one time?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new table called Counter as example the table contains:

```
 post_id|views
```

when ever the user visit the page you increment this counter

or you can add a field called views in the same posts table

if you want to count unique views you may store IP ADDRESS as will and check if the ip exists you don't increment that view.

You can get the ip address in php like this:

```
 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way doing that would be using cookies you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958930/cookie-page-counter-in-php) for it.